# Building a project with Spring boot as backend and angular4 as front end

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot

I would like to develop a web application with angular4 as front end and spring boot as back end first ,and after that create the android version .

searching in google i found that there is a lot of methods , the first one is create a Spring boot project which includes an angular 4 folder (generated with angular CLI ) which means one project in total .

the second one : completly separate the 2 projects , one for spring , the other for angular4 , and the client will use the api Rest to communicate with spring tools.

which one is the best method ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: it sohuld be 2 different projects.

Comment: The second one seems to be the better approach as your rest API will be completely independent and can be used in any other application if needed. Since you are planning on creating an android version as well this approach will surely benefit you..

Comment: I think using separate projects for front end & back end is the suitable solution. There are many advantages of it.

Comment: @Pratyay :    i was so much hesitated about this , thank you so much for help , and what do you think about spring is it better to use the architecture of multi modules ?

Comment: @dzrkot thank you so much for your help , a appreciate that

Comment: @ChamaraMaduranga thank you so much for you help :) :) !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Back end and front end should be developed separately because:

- they use different technologies (java and typescript)
- different build systems (maven and npm)
- back end can be developed not only for angular, but also for other clients
- it is easier to mantain two different projects that use unrelated technologies
- it is simpler to change from one technology to another when needed

Eventually you can deploy them as a single packet including the dist directory in the jar. But also in this case I suggest to have a gateway in front of your app redirecting to the back end for api requests and handling directly static resources (js, html, css...)

Answer (score 1):

I think everybody is agreeing you should separate the projects, because clients (Angular 4, Ionic Framework or a fat client) should never be bounded to and Backend Project.

And btw. you should use Ionic Framework instead of Angular 4. It is based on Angular, but you can build Hybrid Apps for Web/Android and IOS.